# Rails 3 - constructor action in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action

I need to store a value from the database in a variable, and I need to access this variable from all the actions in my controller.

For example, I have the controller `home` which has 3 actions:

- about
- contact
- blog

I tried to store the value to a variable in `application_controller.rb`, but this did not work.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about persisting a value to share in controllers and actions like a currently_logged_in_user? Sorry, I am struggling to understand your English

Comment: yes, something like you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about persistence. To get around the fact website are stateless you persist data by storing it in a cookie. Rails gives you a convenient way of doing this called a session hash.
You can also use the flash hash (This is also a session hash)
At the point where you get the value that you wish to store simply call

```
session[:some_variable] = some_variable
```

Then when you want to retrieve that variable just call

```
some_variable = session[:some_variable]
```

Replace some_variable with a something that makes sense to you

If you want to do this for all controller actions then a before_filter can be useful
Read here about before_filters http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

Do not store large objects or arrays of objects in the session. If you need to keep a reference to an active_record object then store just the ID of the record then you can retrieve that record with a find when you need it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access to a specific variable in all your controller, just do the following.

Into the application controller :

```
before_filter :set_my_variables

private
def set_my_variables
  @variable = MyModel.find(YOUR_CONDITION)
end
```

And for instance, in your home controller, you will be able to access to @variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is about persistence which would involve use of the session.

Comment: yah, I didn't understand his question ... :/